# Python Refuses to change variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python will not change my variable of Ace, Jack, Queen or King, to 10 when asked, instead it seems to skip the while loop and just go along.

I'm using python 3.5.

```
Ace = "Ace"
Jack = "Jack"
Queen = "Queen"
King = "King"

x = [Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]
x1 = random.choice(x)   
x2 = random.choice(x)

# this array is irrelevant to the question.
suit = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
suit1 = random.choice(suit)
suit2 = random.choice(suit)
while suit1 == suit2:
    suit2 = random.choice(suit)

Ace = "Ace"
Jack = "Jack"
Queen = "Queen"
King = "King"

while x1 == ["Jack", "Queen" , "King"]:
    x1 == 10

while x2 == ["Jack" , "Queen" , "King"]:
    x2 == 10

print ("Your cards are the " + str(x1) + " of " + str(suit1) + 
       " and the " + str(x2) + " of " + str(suit2))
print (str(x1) + " " + str(x2))

# When it tries to add the two variables here, it comes up with an error, 
# as it cannot add "King" to "10", since "King" is not a number.
total = (int(x1) + int(x2))
```

Comment: This code makes little sense and I think you need to brush up with a tutorial (like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html)).

Comment: Your x1, x2 variables are randomly set to a single card.  It is impossible for them to be equal to a list of three cards!  Perhaps you want ``x1 in [Jack, Queen, King]``.  And the test should be an ``if``, not a ``while``.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all sorts of things wrong with this code, but consider it an opportunity to play with classes. Consider the following:

```
class Face(object):
    def __init__(self, face, value):
        self.face = face
        self.value = value
    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
    def __str__(self):
        return self.face
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.face
```

Now you can make cards such as:

```
card = Face('king',13)
card #will return 'king'
str(card) #will return 'king'
int(card) #will return 13
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just started with code like, 2 days ago so it probably hurts your head to look at, sorry! This class thing looks kind of important so I'll start using it!

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
while x1 == ["Jack", "Queen" , "King"]:
    x1 == 10
```

With:

```
while x1 in ["Jack", "Queen" , "King"]:
    x1 = 10
```

The issue with the first line is that it didn't check to see if *x1* was in the list of face cards, instead it tested whether *x1* actually was a list of facecards.

The issue with the second line is that `==` is an equality test.  You want just `=` which is an assignment.

Comment: Worked, Sort of. Now the entire second half of my code wont work. I have no idea.